# Is this atomic set and get in MariaDB / MySQL: `UPDATE t SET col = @my_var := col + 1 WHERE id = 123`?

Tags: mysql, mariadb, update, concurrency, isolation-level

I want to atomically update a single row and get its value.

I discovered today that MariaDB / MySQL has this additional way of setting user variables using the assignment operator `:=`, described e.g. [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/assignment-operators.html#operator_assign-value).

I wonder therefore if the following statement, followed by checking the value of `@my_var`, accomplishes what I want:

`UPDATE t SET col = @my_var := col + 1 WHERE id = 123;`

It seems it should, but I'd like to confirm with the pundits.

---

(I know there's also `SELECT .. FOR UPDATE`.)

Comment: I don't mean to be disrespectful, but can't you test this? I think transactions might be your friend in this case?

Comment: @Vérace - Thank you for the suggestion - not disrespectful at all. For one, writing code testing concurrency reliably is a non-trivial task, and certainly much longer than asking SO experts, who probably know off-hand. For two, I prefer to leave a trace of this online so that the next person with this issue doesn't have to test it too. Again, asking on SO as opposed to testing it myself, after which I may or likely may not have the time to post the results somewhere, seems better.

Comment: Ah, yes, a record of what happened... That's what this site aims to be. Well, if you throw together a [fiddle](dbfiddle.uk) and can't solve it yourself, ping me back and I'll take a look (no guarantees! :-) ) - and if you can, answer your own question...

Comment: a user defined variable is a ssessipon variable, so evbery update would overwrite this variable. and the last one who set it, is the value you get

Comment: Show us what _else_ is involved.  @variables may be disallowed in this context in a subsequent version.  And there may be a better way to do the task at hand.  See also IODKU and LAST_INSERT_ID().

Answer (score 0):

I confirm that **yes, this is atomic**.

---

This is what I wanted to avoid, but in the end, I wrote a Python script testing this. I'm pasting it below for reference. The prerequisite is a schema `my_schema` with the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE `t` (
 `id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `col` int(10) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;

INSERT INTO `t` (id, col) VALUES (1, -1);
```

Python script below. Note that you need to comment / uncomment one of the two 'SELECT' lines as needed.

```
import mysql.connector
import random
import string
import threading
import time

# How many threads to run.
num_worker_threads = 30
# Flag to signal to threads that they should finish.
should_threads_finish = False
values = []

def main():
    global should_threads_finish    

    # Start threads.
    print('Starting threads.')
    threads = []
    for i in range(num_worker_threads):
        t = threading.Thread(target=worker, kwargs={'i':i})
        t.start()
        threads.append(t)

    # Let threads run for a while.
    time.sleep(8)

    # Stop threads.
    print('Stopping threads.')
    should_threads_finish = True
    for t in threads:
        t.join()

    # Verify that values queried from DB form a sequence increasing by 1.
    values_sorted = sorted(values)
    for i in range(len(values_sorted)):
        if i != values_sorted[i]:
            print(values_sorted)
            raise RuntimeError('Set and get was not atomic: ' + str(i) + ' vs ' + str(values_sorted[i]))

# What each thread should do.
def worker(i):
    print('Worker ' + str(i) + ' starting.')
    while True:
        if should_threads_finish:
            print('Worker ' + str(i) + ' finishing.')
            break
        # Do work.
        cnx = mysql.connector.connect(host='localhost', database='mysql', user='root', password='root')
        cur = cnx.cursor()

        # Get random name for user variable.
        var_name = ''.join(random.choice(string.ascii_uppercase + string.digits) for _ in range(10))

        # Do the UPDATE.
        cur.execute("UPDATE my_schema.t SET col = @%s := col + 1 WHERE id = 1", (var_name,))
        cnx.commit()

        # Get either the user variable value or actually select from the table.
        cur.execute("SELECT @%s", (var_name,))
        # cur.execute("SELECT col FROM my_schema.t WHERE id = 1")
        row = cur.fetchone()
        values.append(int(row[0]))

        cnx.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

As expected, when selecting the user variable, I'm getting no exception, meaning that the sequence of values queried increased exactly by 1. For my use case, this is a good enough check that this is atomic.

Also as expected, when selecting the value directly from the table (not using the user variable), I'm getting exceptions, signifying non atomicity.